How to use UserSingleton in Fragment
When I Login at LoginActivity, I save the user data returned from the user into UserSingleton and transfer it to MainActivity as follows: enter image description here
But why when I use it in SellFragment like this:enter image description here
then in the paragraph:  user = UserDataSingleton.getInstance().getUser(); user is null again?
I tried using a User object that I saved in another Activity and it worked fine. I really don't understand why?
